# Why does the Italian word for comedy, "commedia", have a double 'm'?

Tags: romance-languages

Why does the Italian word for comedy, "commedia", have a double 'm'? It comes from Latin "comoedia", with a single 'm'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefix *com-* is fairly common in Latin—but specifically before a labial consonant, not before a vowel. (Before a vowel it becomes *co-* instead, as in *coalescō*.) As a result, *comm-* is much more common than *com-*.

So I assume it gained a second *m* under the influence of terms like *commozione* and *commenda*, which come from *com-* attached to a root starting with M.

Comment: cf. Wiese 1904 *Altitalienisches Elementarbuch*, who also explains it with analogy but from the cases with ad-, con-, in- and sub-, "Durch Einfluß der unter 2. besprochenen Assimilationen bei Worten, die mit a-, co-, i- beginnen: *ammen, commedia, immagine*; hierher gehört auch *ommettere* durch Einfluß von *commettere*." (pp. 60-61) https://archive.org/details/altitalienisches00wiesuoft/page/60/mode/2up